# Get deployment status in GKE with api or with SDK (programmatically )

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, monitoring, gcloud

I am building a custom dashboard for monitoring more than 20 clusters. For that I need to get the status of GKE workloads as shown in the GCP UI using any of the programmatical way (api/sdk/gcloud). The image describes what info I am looking for.
Also I can't use kubernetes API as I dont have access for cluster but just for GKE console/dashboard (GCP UI).

[image]

Comment: Stack overflow encourages questions that show an attempt to solve the problem instead of "How do I?" questions. This question may get down-voted and closed.

Comment: Kubernetes Engine and the Cloud Console incorporate 2 distinct APIs. Google's (proprietary for GKE) [Kubernetes Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/) (aka "container" service) and the (general-purpose) [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.25/). The former is used to create Kubernetes Engine clusters, node pools etc. as a kind of meta or control-plane API. The latter is used manage a cluster and its resources as a kind of micro or data-plane API.

Comment: For Cloud Console "Workloads", the Kubernetes API is being used to list Kubernetes resources: Deployments, Stateful Sets, Daemon Sets etc., their config e.g. revisions and to list associated Pods and their details. You would need to use the Kubernetes API preferably though one of its SDKs (e.g. [`client-go`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) or [Kubernetes Python Client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python)).

Comment: However (!) I encourage you to review the wealth of Kubernetes tooling as it's very likely that something close to what you want to do already exists. You show Cloud Console's tooling. Rhetorical: why not just use this?

Comment: @DazWilkin Sorry, I forgot to mention an important point, which is I can't use k8s API (general-purpose) as I don't have access for the clusters. I have access for only the GKE console and equivalent APIs.

Comment: The **only** way that to enumerate a cluster's resources is if you directly or indirectly have access to an identity that has access **and** you're using a tool that uses the Kubernetes API. No tool is able to overcome either of those restrictions. Cloud Console is using your Google identity to authenticate you to the clusters and it is using the Kubernetes API to access the clusters' resources.

Comment: Okay. I will look into it. I am trying to achieve it using this doc [link](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/container/latest/google.cloud.container_v1beta1.services.cluster_manager.ClusterManagerClient#google_cloud_container_v1beta1_services_cluster_manager_ClusterManagerClient_get_cluster)

Comment: Please see my initial comment above. This Python library is an implementation of Google's Kubernetes Engine API. It only provides methods to e.g. enumerate|get clusters, node pools etc. It **doesn't** provide a mechanism to get a cluster's resources (as shown in the Console diagram). For that you **must** use the Kubernetes API.

Comment: @DazWilkin Yes. Thanks a lot for clarifying. I have read all the docs and I agree with you. I am wondering if its possible to use gcp service account/IAM for authenticating to Kubebernetes API. So that I dont need cluster access to achieve this. Because as you said somehow gcp console (ui) is using kubernetes API to get those values. And with just reader access to the console I am able to see those details. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from kubernetes import client, config
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'test-devops-646fy5644.json'
import google.auth.transport.requests
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
from google.cloud import container_v1beta1 as cv1

def get_cluster_endpoint():
    # Create a client
    client = cv1.ClusterManagerClient()
    # Initialize request argument(s)
    request = cv1.GetClusterRequest(
        project_id="test-devops",
        zone="us-central1-a",
        cluster_id="cluster-test",
    )
    # Make the request
    response = client.get_cluster(request=request).endpoint
    # Handle the response
    return response


def test_gke():
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(os.getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'), scopes=SCOPES)
    # cluster_manager_client = ClusterManagerClient(credentials=credentials)
    # cluster = cluster_manager_client.get_cluster(project_id, zone, cluster_id)
    configuration = client.Configuration()
    configuration.host = "https://"+get_cluster_endpoint()+":443"
    configuration.verify_ssl = False
    credentials.refresh(request)
    print(credentials.token)
    configuration.api_key = {"authorization": "Bearer " + credentials.token}
    client.Configuration.set_default(configuration)
    v1 = client.AppsV1Api()
    print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
    deployment = v1.read_namespaced_deployment(name='nginx-deployment', namespace='default')
    print(deployment)
test_gke()
```

Here, I have used just the GCP service account key(JSON) with KubernetesEngineAPIViewer Role for accessing KubernertesAPI(general-purpose) which solves the problem.